# Sorting a LinkedHashMap in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a HashMap by values.
I'm currently using the following code

```
public static Map<String, Float> sortByValue(Map<String, Float> unsorted_map){

    Map<String, Float> sorted_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Float>();

    try{
        // 1. Convert Map to List of Map
        List<Map.Entry<String, Float>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Float>>(unsorted_map.entrySet());

        // 2. Sort list with Collections.sort(), provide a custom Comparator
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Float>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Float> o1,
                    Map.Entry<String, Float> o2) {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        // 3. Loop the sorted list and put it into a new insertion order Map LinkedHashMap
        for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : list) {
            sorted_map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return sorted_map;

}
```

but the output is wrong. 
In particular, values begin in descending order then, after a 0.0 value, they become in ascending order (as the second data column shows).

```
---> 1985 0.54660827
---> 2002 0.45290402
---> 1993 0.40605184
---> 2015 0.3591997
---> 2000 0.34358233
---> 1980 0.2811128
---> 2008 0.24987808
---> 1990 0.23426071
---> 1983 0.23426071
---> 1986 0.21864335
---> 1977 0.18740855
---> 1992 0.1717912
---> 2009 0.14055647
---> 2006 0.12493904
---> 2011 0.031234872
---> 2001 0.015617436
---> 1975 0.0
---> 1997 0.031234723
---> 2004 0.046852008
---> 1988 0.062469445
---> 2013 0.07808688
---> 1978 0.07808688
---> 2005 0.1093216
---> 1981 0.14055632
---> 1976 0.14055632
---> 2014 0.14055632
---> 1999 0.15617377
---> 1994 0.20302577
---> 1987 0.20302577
---> 2010 0.2186432
---> 1991 0.24987794
---> 1989 0.24987794
---> 1996 0.28111264
---> 2012 0.28111264
---> 2003 0.29673007
---> 1998 0.29673007
---> 2007 0.31234753
---> 1984 0.3904344
---> 1982 0.42166913
---> 1979 0.5309907
---> 1995 0.73401666
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a TreeMap which sorts itself?

Comment: @puhlen because it sorts by key, not by value.

Comment: This implementation looks correct to me.  I'd honestly actually suspect the code you're using to print out the map, or not assigning the sorted map somehow when you call this method.

Comment: This code works fine in other point of the application.

Comment: So I tried to replicate your problem and I wasn't able to https://repl.it/DbOU/0. Can you show a sample of data that will show off your problem?

Comment: Please show how you call this method and how you print the map. Maybe you are just not assigning the result and print the original map instead? Did you debug the code and checked the actual value of the return statement?

Comment: Input data are ordered by key, which represents YEAR.

Comment: @Martin Nyolt, Louis Wasserman GREAT!!! In this case I'm not assigning the result unlike the other parts of codes where it works! Thank you so much!!! And thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code some should works. i write code like you and it works, here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Float> unsortFloatMap = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
    unsortFloatMap.put(1985, 0.54660827f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2002, 0.45290402f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(1993, 0.40605184f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2015, 0.3591997f);

    unsortFloatMap.put(1975, 0.0f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(1997, 0.031234723f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2004, 0.046852008f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2005, 0.1093216f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2003, 0.29673007f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(1998, 0.29673007f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(2007, 0.31234753f);
    unsortFloatMap.put(1995, 0.73401666f);

    System.out.println("Unsort Float Map......");
    printMap(unsortFloatMap);

    System.out.println("Sorted Float Map......");
    Map<Integer, Float> sortedFloatMap = sortByFloatValue(unsortFloatMap);
    printMap(sortedFloatMap);
}

// pretty print a map
public static <K, V> void printMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

private static Map<Integer, Float> sortByFloatValue(Map<Integer, Float> unsortMap) {
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Float> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Float> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    /// Loop the sorted list and put it into a new insertion order Map
    /// LinkedHashMap
    Map<Integer, Float> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Float>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry : list) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedMap;
}
```

Output is:

```
Unsort Float Map......
Key : 2002 Value : 0.45290402
Key : 2003 Value : 0.29673007
Key : 1985 Value : 0.54660827
Key : 1975 Value : 0.0
Key : 2007 Value : 0.31234753
Key : 2004 Value : 0.046852008
Key : 2005 Value : 0.1093216
Key : 1995 Value : 0.73401666
Key : 1993 Value : 0.40605184
Key : 1998 Value : 0.29673007
Key : 2015 Value : 0.3591997
Key : 1997 Value : 0.031234723
Sorted Float Map......
Key : 1975 Value : 0.0
Key : 1997 Value : 0.031234723
Key : 2004 Value : 0.046852008
Key : 2005 Value : 0.1093216
Key : 2003 Value : 0.29673007
Key : 1998 Value : 0.29673007
Key : 2007 Value : 0.31234753
Key : 2015 Value : 0.3591997
Key : 1993 Value : 0.40605184
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorting code is OK. Your print seems to fail. Check **negative** numbers printing.

Try this sorting using Stream API

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map 
    = unsorted_map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Integer::compareTo))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> a,
               LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
```

Collector make `LinkedHashMap` node by identity with "take one" collision resolver.

Answer (score 1):

The most reasonable explanation is that your printing code fails to print the `-` in front of negative numbers. Your sorting code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.JavaExample;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class HashSetSorted 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>(); 
        names.add("Asker");
        names.add("Crak"); 
        names.add("Bayliss"); 
        names.add("Mohna"); 
        names.add("Dina");
        System.out.println("HashSet before sorting : " + names); 
        // Sorting HashSet using List 
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>(names);
        Collections.sort(tempList); 
        System.out.println("HashSet element in sorted order : " + tempList);     
        // Sorting HashSet using TreeSet
        TreeSet<String> sorted = new TreeSet<String>(names);
        System.out.println("HashSet sorted using TreeSet : " + sorted);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. Indent 4 spaces on each line to make a code block.